# Problemas al intentar hacer update desde checkedlistbox a una tabla en sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

Estimados tengo un checkedlistbox que lo lleno a traves de una consulta sql de la siguiente manera:

```
Try
        Using loConexion As New SqlConnection(conString)
            Dim loDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT idRespu, descripRespu FROM ocl.tblrespuesta WHERE idRespu LIKE '302%'", loConexion)
            loDataAdapter.Fill(moDataTable)
            chk302.DataSource = moDataTable
            chk302.DisplayMember = "descripRespu"
            chk302.ValueMember = "idRespu"
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

el problema es cuando quiero actualizar los valores de mi checkedlistbox hacia mi tabla en sql, que lo realizo a traves del siguiente codigo:

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(conString)
    cn.Open()
    For i = 0 To chk302.Items.Count - 1

        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE OCL.tblDetalleRespuMultiple SET snRespu = @snRespu, fechaRespu = GETDATE() WHERE dniUsu = '" & txtDNI.Text & "' AND idPregun = '302' AND aniosegui='1'  AND idRespu =@idRespu;"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idRespu", chk302.Items(i))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@snRespu", chk302.GetItemCheckState(i))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    cn.Close()
```

Y despues de ejecutar el update mediante el boton Guardar .. me sale el siguiente error en la linea de : cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

```
{{"No hay ninguna asignación de tipo de objeto System.Data.DataRowView a un tipo nativo de un proveedor administrado conocido."}}
```

Quisiera saber si estoy recorriendo correctamente los valores de cada checkbox al momento de hacer el UPDATE, o talvez estoy fallando en otra parte del codigo. De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Si haces `var a = chk302.Items(i);` ¿qué valor guarda a?

Comment: Hola Antonio.. cuando asigno la linea que me indicaste, el valor que guarda a = Nothing , y despues me sale el error : "La conversión del tipo 'DataRowView' en el tipo 'String' no es válida."   Tambien edite mi pregunta poniendo toda la info en texto.

Comment: Hola Fred! Eso quiere decir que no estás haciendo correctamente la asignación, intenta con `chk302.Items(i).Value`, o algo así...  tal vez .Text...

Comment: @Fred: el error lo marca desde la primera iteración?

Comment: Asi es Antonio..  el problema es como leer todos los valores del checkedlistbox ya sea que esten marcados o no.